# C# Windows form text box format with data binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form with a text box: txtMyText.

txtMyText.Text is Bound to a data source: long lMyLongValue.

On the form I would like the value to display as a six digit value with leading zeros.  Example 000123.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Binding.Format event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx), can be pretty suitable for your needs, if not, you can bind it not to `long` property, but to `string` property and handle conversion from `long` -> `srtring` and vice versa "by hand".

for convert it into formatted string use pretty simple example:

```
    long l  =13;
    string sformat = l.ToString("000000"); // 000013
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. When using the IDE, I had entered the custom format property in the dialog box as "000000". When this was converted into code it was changed to "\"000000\"". Moral: Don't add the quotes in the IDE dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Yes, follow link
[How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)